# ARKit Version 1.5 can detect Vertical surface?

Tags: ios, arkit

If I am not wrong ARKit does not support vertical surface detection.

But

According to https://developer.apple.com/news/

and

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01242018b

> OS 11 is the biggest AR platform in the world, allowing you to create unparalleled augmented reality experiences for hundreds of millions of iOS users. Now you can build even more immersive experiences by taking advantage of the latest features of ARKit, available in iOS 11.3 beta. With improved scene understanding, your app can see and place virtual objects on **vertical surfaces**, and more accurately map irregularly shaped surfaces.

Does it mean that version 1.5 can able to detect vertical surface too. ?

Comment: Yes, from ARKit 1.5 in iOS 11.3 (now in beta), it can detect vertical surface.
See [here](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/)  for the news.

Comment: @Kerberos Thank you very much for most valuable comment :)